# How to use browser back/forward buttons to navigate React state change history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

I have a Dashboard.js page component at a path like "/dashboard" that lets users navigate between 3 tables all by altering its state while the URL stays the same (the route is not changing). I'm trying to add browser back/forward button support for these state changes, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to push the state changes to history and restore them in the component when the user clicks the back/forward buttons.

Within my component I tried adding `this.props.history.push(this.props.location.path, this.state)` to one of my main functions that does `setState()` to see if that would allow back button navigation. It definitely adds to the history, because now I can press the back button a few times before it leaves the page, but the page looks the same (the component doesn't get the old state back). How and where do I make the component "restore the old state" when the back button is pressed?

Here's a basic example of my component structure:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    // table data, current table, etc.
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // get records from db, set state
  }

  navigateExample() {
    // various functions like this one set state,
    // basically navigating between tables
    this.props.history.push(this.props.location.path, this.state) // <--here?
    this.setState({ table: newTable })
  }

  render() {
    // renders different table components depending on state
  }
}
```

I apologize if the example code is too vague, my component file is large and I don't know what is relevant to include. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but I believe I was looking for the wrong kind of solution, and I want to leave this bread crumb trail for anybody else thinking they need this in their web app.

I realized it would actually be better to change the URL as the user navigates around the tables. Even though the component is the same, I can pass in a bunch of optional parameters through the route path like so:

```
<Route path="/dashboard/:table?/:group?/:classID?" component={Dashboard} />
```

Then I'll update state by setting a new URL, getting the values out of match.params in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` and setting state with those.

This will have a number of benefits:

- Changing URL's via `history.push` automatically creates a history you can traverse with back/forward buttons
- The state will be synced with this history, since the values come from the URL
- I can choose what level of detail to include in the URL, including important things like "which table" but excluding minor things like "sort column"
- Most importantly, people will be able to share links to an exact part of the dashboard with each other. This follows the principle of "a particular URL should always point to a particular page". I realized that even though these different dashboard tables were all being rendered from a single component, they really count as different "pages" to the user, and users should be able to link directly to them with the right URL.

Edit: solution works as described. This was definitely the way to go, It reduced complexity in my code by a lot.